# Using a viewbox in PanningLayer

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a panorama app for windows phone 7. I have a viewbox, which I want to stretch throughout the PanningLayer of the panorama app. I have removed the PanningTitleLayer. Everything works fine but there is a problem. When I run the app in the emulator, the viewbox is shown partially, you have to swipe it to see the hidden part of the viewbox. When I swipe the viewbox, it slides completely until it is back to the beginning. What I want is that when I swipe the viewbox, it should slide partially and stop, so that a user can see that part of the viewbox which is hidden. How do I do it?